# Is the a shorthand to require a class and instantly initialize it?

Tags: javascript, es6-class

My class exports

```
class MyClass {
    myMethod() {
    } 
}

module.exports = { MyClass }
```

In order to use it's methods I need to

```
const MyClass = require(./myclass)
const myClass = new MyClass()

myClass.myMethod()
```

PLEASE NOTE: I don't want to change the way I'm exporting MyClass

Is there a way to initialize my class on import and amend the declaration of two variables (`MyClass` and `myClass`)?

p.s. I'm not using any transcompilers

Comment: `new require('./myclass')()`?

Comment: FYI, `module.exports = { MyClass }` would mean you need to import it using `const { MyClass } = require('./myclass')` (note the curly brackets in the declaration)

Comment: In my opinion, your current code is better as `import` is meant to import modules and then you consume them the way you want. A shorthand might reduce few characters but will also reduce readability

Comment: @VLAZ would need to be `new (require('./myclass'))()` because order of operations would treat `require` as the constructor instead.

Comment: @VLAZ do you mean `const myClass = new require(./myclass)()` ? If yes ES lint gives me an error "Unexpected use of new with require.eslint(no-new-require). A constructor name should not start with a lowercase letter"

Comment: @anotheruser as Patrick Roberts mentioned, you need brackets around it.

Comment: Ok. So I summed up everything above but still missing something. My code is: `const { MyClass } = new (require("./myclass"))()` and I get `TypeError: require(...) is not a constructor` during code run

Comment: If you have `const { MyClass }` then you're not receiving a single function on `require` but an object. You cannot call an object with `new`.

Comment: @VLAZ does it mean it's not possible to do what I'm asking about?

Comment: `new (require(...).MyClass)()`…?